# XSLT transformation to group similar tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have this XML with `players` and `citizens` sections. Each section has multiple `person` tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
   <players>
      <person>
         <name>joe</name>
         <age>20</age>
      </person>
      <person>
         <name>sam</name>
         <age>23</age>
      </person>
   </players>
   <citizens>
      <person>
         <name>joe</name>
         <city>ny</city>
      </person>
      <person>
         <name>sam</name>
         <city>london</city>
      </person>
   </citizens>
</test>
```

Now I want to transform this so that `person` tags of, `players` and `citizens` sections are merged together based on `name` tag.

This is the output I need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
   <players>
      <person>
         <name>joe</name>
         <age>20</age>
         <city>ny</city>
      </person>
      <person>
         <name>sam</name>
         <age>23</age>
         <city>london</city>
      </person>
   </players>
</test>
```

I want to do an XSLT transformation for this. I tried lots of stuff without luck. Appreciate some help for this.

**Update**: I tried this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="citizens" select="/test/citizens"/>
    <xsl:template match="/test/players">
        <players>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
        </players>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <xsl:variable name="data1" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="data2" select="/test/citizens/person[name=current()/name]/."/>
        <person>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$data1/*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$data2/*">
                <xsl:variable name="element2" select="name(.)"/>
                <xsl:if test="count($data1/*[name()=$element2])=0">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </person>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's almost correct. I just want to get rid of last 2 `person` tags. Please guide me.

```
   <players>
      <person>
         <name>joe</name>
         <age>20</age>
         <city>ny</city>
      </person>
      <person>
         <name>sam</name>
         <age>23</age>
         <city>london</city>
      </person>
   </players>
   <person>
      <name>joe</name>
      <city>ny</city>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>sam</name>
      <city>london</city>
   </person>
```

Comment: I found a lot of different kinds of grouping examples. But didn't find this one.

Comment: Which XSLT version does your processor support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="person-by-name" match="person" use="name" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/test">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="players"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('person-by-name', name, ../../citizens)/city "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Here's another:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/test">
    <xsl:copy>
        <players>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*/person" group-by="name">
                <person>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/*[not(self::name)]"/>
                </person>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </players>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I was trying too, and updated my question with what I got so far. Could you please help me understand what should I change in mine?

Comment: Could you please edit that and post as another answer?

Comment: @abhi I am afraid I don't understand your approach and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: No worries michael. Thank you for the answer. I just tried your solution in http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php quickly. But it gives an error. Is that because it doesn't support 2.0?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like my processor does not support some parts of XSLT 2.0. So I'll have to go for 1.0. Previously I had posted a wrong result above. I updated that and created a new question too. If you have a time, please have a look.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177494/xslt-transformation-to-group-similar-tags-with-xslt-1-0

Comment: "*it looks like my processor does not support some parts of XSLT 2.0.*" Really? Which parts of XSLT 2.0 does it support?

Comment: Hard to find which part of this. But some non-complex 2.0 ones are working fine. Anyway, thank you for the answer again..