# XSLT transformation to group similar tags with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML with `players` and `citizens` sections. Each section has multiple `person` tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
   <players>
      <person>
         <name>joe</name>
         <age>20</age>
      </person>
      <person>
         <name>sam</name>
         <age>23</age>
      </person>
   </players>
   <citizens>
      <person>
         <name>joe</name>
         <city>ny</city>
      </person>
      <person>
         <name>sam</name>
         <city>london</city>
      </person>
   </citizens>
</test>
```

Now I want to transform this so that `person` tags of, `players` and `citizens` sections are merged together based on `name` tag.

This is the output I need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
   <players>
      <person>
         <name>joe</name>
         <age>20</age>
         <city>ny</city>
      </person>
      <person>
         <name>sam</name>
         <age>23</age>
         <city>london</city>
      </person>
   </players>
</test>
```

I want to do an `XSLT 1.0` transformation for this.

I tried this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="citizens" select="/test/citizens"/>
    <xsl:template match="/test/players">
        <players>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
        </players>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <xsl:variable name="data1" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="data2" select="/test/citizens/person[name=current()/name]/."/>
        <person>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$data1/*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$data2/*">
                <xsl:variable name="element2" select="name(.)"/>
                <xsl:if test="count($data1/*[name()=$element2])=0">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </person>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's almost correct. I just want to get rid of last 2 `person` tags. Please guide me.

```
   <players>
      <person>
         <name>joe</name>
         <age>20</age>
         <city>ny</city>
      </person>
      <person>
         <name>sam</name>
         <age>23</age>
         <city>london</city>
      </person>
   </players>
   <person>
      <name>joe</name>
      <city>ny</city>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>sam</name>
      <city>london</city>
   </person>
```

**Note**: I received an [answer for XSLT 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172314/xslt-transformation-to-group-similar-tags), But now I'm looking for a solution with XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this in **XSLT 1.0** would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="citizen-by-name" match="citizens/person" use="name" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/test">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="players"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('citizen-by-name', name)/city "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Another option would be to use the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to *group* the `person` elements from both branches by their `name`.